# Looping Text to Columns Fixed Width on Individual Rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to build a loop that will look at each row in a column of data and split based on the first instance of an " ". I can get this to work on one line but the loop never activates. I tried my best at formatting this code but could not find a tutorial on how to have the commands appear as different colors and whatnot.

```
Dim num
Dim RowCnt As Integer
Dim x As Integer

ActiveCell.Select ' the cell to split
RowCnt = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 'determines #rows in column to split

With ActiveCell ' with block

   For x = 1 To RowCnt ' define # loops

         .Offset(, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=FIND("" "",RC[1],1)" ' determine first " "
         num = .Offset(, -1).Value ' assign the number of chars to 'num' 

                Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(num, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True ' splits once based on 'num'
         
        .Offset(, -1).ClearContents ' clear 
        .Offset(1, 0).Activate

   Next x

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead (tested: works!)

```
Sub updated_delimitter()

start_cell = ActiveCell.AddressLocal
n = Range(start_cell, Range(start_cell).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 'determines #rows in column to split
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For x = 0 To n - 1 ' define # loops
    this_cell = Range(start_cell).Offset(x).AddressLocal
    Range(this_cell).Select
    word_ = Range(this_cell).Value
    split_at = InStr(word_, " ")
    Range(this_cell).TextToColumns Destination:=Range(this_cell), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(split_at, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True ' splits once based on 'num'

   Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

*original code had issues with referencing in relation to 'activecell' which you referenced in the text-to-columns section - removed the with statement and no need to insert num when you can simply store it within VB (getting rid of its placements also mean no code required to remove it...*

---

You could achieve the same in 3 lines of code♦ (w/ for loop) using the following:

```
Sub test2()
    'Range("d2").Select
    With Selection
        .Offset(, 3).Formula2R1C1 = _
            "=LET(x_,RC[-3]:OFFSET(RC[-3],MATCH(0,IFERROR(SEARCH("""",RC[-3]:OFFSET(RC[-3],ROWS(C[-3])-ROWS(RC[-3])-1,0)),0),0)-1,0),IF(ISODD(SEQUENCE(1,2,1,1)),MID(x_,1,IFERROR(SEARCH("" "",x_)-1,LEN(x_))),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("" "",x_)),"""",MID(x_,SEARCH("" "",x_)+2,LEN(x_)))))"
        Range(.AddressLocal, .End(xlDown).Offset(, 1)).Value = Range(Replace(.Offset(, 3).AddressLocal, "$", "") & "#").Value
        .Offset(, 3).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

This uses the function:

```
=LET(x_,D2:OFFSET(D2,MATCH(0,IFERROR(SEARCH("",D2:OFFSET(D2,ROWS(D:D)-ROWS(D2)-1,0)),0),0)-1,0),IF(ISODD(SEQUENCE(1,2,1,1)),MID(x_,1,IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",x_)-1,LEN(x_))),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",x_)),"",MID(x_,SEARCH(" ",x_)+2,LEN(x_)))))
```

... which is an array function that reproduces the original list with relevant cells split as req.

[image: array function]

**REVISED**
[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hKogM5htN_HXHu0fOg?e=jTgvtK) for sample file (requires Microsoft Onedrive a/c - read only file avail.)

[image: Sample Gif - delimitter array function in action!]

---

♦ Office 365 compatibility; '3 lines' ignoring with/end/sub/etc.

ta

---

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will have to spend some time familiarizing myself with the =LET formula you suggested. In the meantime, I tried changing the row offset from 1 to x as you suggested. This successfully loops through each row in the loop but only triggers the body of the code for the first row. The rest are left untouched.

Comment: glad it worked - acccept or leave answer open for better soln for future yses as you deem fit!  (may not have sufficient rep pts though..)  cheers

Comment: @SeanSullivan PS - I updated - if you're feeling brave RE: let function give the revised VB code a go (requires a few columns to the right of D col to be clear) --  :)  peace

Comment: Thanks for the updated code JB. I will try what you provided. I would like to clarify my earlier comment, the .offset(x,0) did not work. It simply looped to the last cell without executing any of the code. I will update when tested your LET function. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: I tried your code as specified a few columns to the right of D. It returned #N/A on all cells in the loop. I thank you for your time. I will continue trying to sort it out! Best.

Comment: Interesting - does the function I've included work by any chance?  and is calcuation on auto or manual?

Comment: Sorry, it does not appear to work. It returns #N/A. The workbook calculations are set to automatic. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you do not have Office 365 compatible version of Excel per caveat in main / original soln above - per: *https://www.digitalcitizen.life/find-exact-version-microsoft-office/#ftoc-heading-5* you could execute cmd prompt: *reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer"* and if you see word application 16.0 you have the latest/best.  In any case I've revised answer to include a link to a sample file with the function/code working on my machine (tested on another - as I would suspect - no glitches).. at least you have a working solution in the end though - as I understand

Comment: (if still in duobt - I've thrown in a gif to demonstrate what *should* happen) - you'll need to modify the function if you've inserted the function too far to the left / otherwise as it works in this particular case RE: its relative position to other cells (that's not to say it won't work in other positions of course, just that referencing will be out of sync with the original construct if inserted elsewhere without due modification - obviously...) ta

Comment: This is strange - the offset (x,0) didn't work even though you say 'next x' - ummm.... did you try the file link I provided?

Comment: Ok- all fixed-  give that a go (see above)... i.e. VB without long fancy 365 function avial.  if you want to see it work its way down each cell/iteration of loop, remove the first and last instance of 'screenupdating' bit... ta

Comment: @SeanSullivan - did this new vb code work or what?

Comment: @SeanSullivan ?? this is spacewaste = 15 min chars ignore

Comment: Must've spent 2 weekends on not a peep once it started working. Wow. Up/Down vote accoridngly for future uses pls ta

Comment: Hi JB-007. I still haven't got this working. I apologize for upsetting you. Not to go into details but I have been taxed in multiple parts of my life recently. I appreciate your weekends spent just helping me. You are a kind person. I think this project will have to be put to one side for the time being due to what I wrote above. Thank you.

Comment: As you wish - but I'm perplexed (and no - you didn't upset me - I was just keen to know whether you had it solved or not - I hat unsolved puzzles 
so please don't interpret words s.t. character limits in the absence of the majority of 'missing' communication (per  7 %- 38 %- 55  Mehrabian's principle https:// followed by tinyurl.com/48bc2kys) - which effectively states we're only acquiring 7% of the intended/complete communication (the rest, like body language, tone, so easily misunderstood/left open to subjective interpretation etc. is completely lost! ).  Did you try the workbook link?

Comment: Was only perturbed by lack of response - nothing else - it's good to know after a of effort undertaken (which is something I enjoy doing btw) - to know whether it 'came right' - I really want to help you in this regard - but if you want to put aside we can do that.. let me know when/if you change your mind - keep well buddy, sorry it didn't work (curious whether the soln I provided is what you're looking for but you can't get it woking your side, or you can but it doesn't address the question... let me know - then we leave it until / if you pick this project up again...! keep well brother

Answer (score 0):

I was able to cheat the answer. The issue is the Text to Columns always referred to the first cell until the sub ended. My solution was to make the looped code its own sub and call it in a separate subs loop. That way it ends the sub each time before being called again.